# Android deleting the micro_kind thumbnails after image file deletion

Tags: android, mediastore

I am populating a gridview with MICRO_KIND thumbnails using the following:

```
  /* Find images of interest   */   
  imagecursor =    getActivity().getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CON  TENT_URI,
                columns,
                MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA + " like ? ",
                new String[]{"%/houseTab" + currentHouseNumber + "/%"},
                null);

/* Retrieve MICRO_KIND Thumbnails   */
int id = imagecursor.getInt(image_column_index);
thumbnails[i] = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(
                    getActivity().getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), id,
                    MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND, null);
```

The retrieve process works perfectly; the issue happen when I delete the actual image files I can not delete the MICRO_KIND Thumbnails.  This is what I am using right now and the files images gets deleted but the MICRO_KIND does not get deleted and still visible in the gridview even after a refresh.  To get rid of the thumbnail I have to turn off the device or do a unmount/mount of the sdcard.

```
  int count = imagecursor.getCount();
    int image_column_index = imagecursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID);
    ContentResolver cr = getActivity().getApplicationContext().getContentResolver();

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        new File(arrPath[i]).delete(); // Delete the actual image file
        imagecursor.moveToPosition(i);

        long id = imagecursor.getInt(image_column_index);

        /* Delete the thumbnails ???? Not working    */
        cr.delete(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.IMAGE_ID +
                "= ?",new String[]{"" + id});
```

By the way arrPath is retrieve from the mediastore using the following:

```
int dataColumnIndex = imagecursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
arrPath[i] = imagecursor.getString(dataColumnIndex);
```

I also try to following to delete the thumbnails but also without any success.

```
 MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(
            getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
            new String[]{arrPath[i]},
            null,
            new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                    refreshImages();
                }
            });
```

So how do I remove this entry from the database so the when the imagecursor is refreshed after the file deletion the imagecursor is empty and no MICRO_KIND or any data for that matter is returned???

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully this will help others.  I manage to delete the entry from the mediastore hence the MICRO_KIND thumbnails using the following:

```
 Uri uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            id);
    cr.delete(uri,null,null);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm having this same problem, I couldn't find any way to delete the MICRO_KIND thumbnails no matter what I did, so I peeked through the MediaStore source code and saw that there were references to the /sdcard/DCIM/.thumbnails/.thumbdata3--##### file, and it looks like thats where the MICRO_KIND thumbnails are stored.

The MediaStore database holds records that point to the thumbnail files in the /sdcard/DCIM/.thumbnails folder, so when you delete a thumbnail from MediaStore, it also deletes the file under that folder (which appear to be the MINI_KIND thumbnails since they are considerably larger than MICRO_KIND).

When I deleted the /sdcard/DCIM/.thumbnails/.thumbdata--BLAHBLAH file through ADB, it fixed my problem, the correct thumbnails loaded and I noticed the file instantly was recreated.

I also noticed when I deleted the file throught he ContentResolver like you did, and then queried the MINI_KIND thumbnails, they always loaded correctly.

So my answer (which seems more like a workaround than an answer) was to query the MINI_KIND thumbnails from the MediaStore, and extract a thumbnail from that:

```
BitmapFactory.Options opts = new BitmapFactory.Options();
opts.inSampleSize = 3;
Bitmap out = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(contentResolver, imageId, MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND, opts);
out = ThumbnailUtils.extractThumbnail(out, 96, 96);
```

And delete the thumbnail using user2553585's answer
Hope this helps